# Faster way to detect the brightest of several spots in a image with imagemagick?

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have several detected polygons in an image and I try to find the brightest of them. I found a way but its relatively slow when it compares a lot of polygons.

The code does the following:

1. It resizes the area to the same size and
2. returns the [**`format "%\[mean\]"`**](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/escape.php) value and return the biggest one

As far as I can see the process get slowed down by the resizing command. 
**Any idea or different approach to fasten that algorithm?**

---

### Example

Here an example where just two polygons are compared. It still take `~0.3457 sec` for the calculation.

```php
// the example image
$image = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmPYh.png";

// get parameters of the image
list ($width, $height, $type) = getimagesize ("$image");

// the polygones
$quadrilateral[0] = array('pointA' => array ('x' => 50, 'y' => 105),
                          'pointB' => array ('x' => 470.593, 'y' => 105),
                          'pointC' => array ('x' => 475.714, 'y' => 398.404),
                          'pointD' => array ('x' => 50, 'y' => 405.835));
$quadrilateral[1] = array('pointA' => array ('x' => 525, 'y' => 185),
                          'pointB' => array ('x' => 935, 'y' => 185),
                          'pointC' => array ('x' => 935, 'y' => 477),
                          'pointD' => array ('x' => 525, 'y' => 477));

// measure time
$start_time = microtime(true);

// start with zero
$brightest = 0;

// loop through $quadrilateral
foreach ( $quadrilateral as $key => $q) {

    $resize_factor = .5; // resize factor for check if it works faster
    $newHeight = $height*$resize_factor;
    $newWidth = $width*$resize_factor;

    // resize image and return %mean            
    $command = "convert $image \\
                -background none \\
                -gravity NorthWest  \\
                -extent ".$width."x".$height." \\
                -alpha set -virtual-pixel transparent \\
                -distort Perspective \"\\
                    ".$q['pointA']['x'].",".$q['pointA']['y']." 0,0 \\
                    ".$q['pointB']['x'].",".$q['pointB']['y']." $newWidth,0 \\
                    ".$q['pointC']['x'].",".$q['pointC']['y']." $newWidth,$newHeight \\
                    ".$q['pointD']['x'].",".$q['pointD']['y']." 0,$newHeight \"\\
                -crop ".$newWidth."x".$newHeight."+0+0 +repage \\
                -format \"%[mean]\" info: ";    

    $output = shell_exec("$command");

    $draw =  "polygon ".$q['pointA']['x'].",".$q['pointA']['y']." "
                       .$q['pointB']['x'].",".$q['pointB']['y']." "
                       .$q['pointC']['x'].",".$q['pointC']['y']." "
                       .$q['pointD']['x'].",".$q['pointD']['y']." ";

    // check $output is brighter then $brightest
    if ($output > $brightest) {

        $result = $draw;                                        
        $brightest = $output;

    }

}

// measure time
$end_time = microtime(true);

$command = "convert  $image \\
                -fill none -stroke red -strokewidth 3 \\
                -draw \"$result\" \\
                $image2";

$output = shell_exec("$command");

echo "<pre>".number_format(($end_time-$start_time), 4)  . " sec</pre>\n";
```

[image: result brightest part is marked]

Comment: You are essentially distorting the *entire* image to get the rectangle you are measuring to fill a rectangle. Maybe you could crop the image first to a containing rectangle before distorting...

Comment: Are the actual rectangles you are detecting fairly uniform? If so, you could crop the image to a minimum containing rectangle and then crop out the central 20-50% of that and measure its average brightness. Can your real shapes contain "holes" - like the letter "e" for example?

Comment: Nope they are not too uniform as the photo angle is variable. Also the shape can contain holes. Thats why I use the [Canny Edge Detection](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=25405) in combination with [Hough line detector](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=25476) to detect the polygons.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your background, and lighting conditions, and the shapes involved, you may find you can get there faster with a *"Connected Component Analysis"*. It also potentially means you don't have to do the step you did previously to determine your rectangles so the time may be even better - what I mean is that this not only tells you the mean brightness of the shapes, but it also finds them for you.

At the commandline it looks like this:

```
convert input.png -fuzz 30% -fill black -opaque black \
  -define connected-components:verbose=true           \
  -define connected-components:area-threshold=500     \
  -connected-components 8 -auto-level output.png
```

**Output**

```
Objects (id: bounding-box centroid area mean-color):
0: 996x600+0+0 504.2,305.1 349020 srgba(0,0,0,1)
3: 429x304+49+104 261.0,254.1 128277 srgba(187,184,186,1)
10: 415x294+523+185 730.4,331.7 120303 srgba(177,156,161,1)
```

You would then simply compare the brightnesses of the mean colours of the two objects listed above.

[image]

Maybe you can slip in a `-resize 50%x50%` immediately after loading the image and before the [`-fuzz`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#fuzz) to speed it up even further. If your real input image is a JPEG, you can also maybe use a `resize on load` to read it in even faster from disk.

Comment: Thx for the approach @mark-setchell it's quite fast. Unfortunately it doesn't work for me as my background is usually more complex. I'll try if can lay a mask over the background and following these method then...

Comment: Can you maybe reduce the image down to 50% in each dimension to speed it up then?

Comment: Good idea, I reduced the original image and then checked the result. With 9 different polygons it needs the following times: `100% => ~42s`, `50% => ~32s` and `25% => ~34s`. There is a little improvement from 100% to 50% but with further reduction no more. It seams like `shell_exec()` takes time itself... Maybe it faster to use the implemented php5 commands...

Comment: So I implemented it just with php5 commands and it has exactly the same running time. For me that means its the perspective distortion which makes the process slow. But so far I have no better idea to compare the polygons...

Comment: That is why I suggested trimming to the minimum bounding rectangle before doing the perspective distort in my initial comment. Another option may be to do the various polygons in parallel if you have a decent 2+ core CPU...

Comment: I tried that now again but it doesn't speed up the process. For test reasons I just cropped each polygon to the minimum bounding rectangle...

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be the fastest way of doing it...

- Fill your image with black.
- Draw a white filled polygon to match the shape you are trying to analyse for brightness.
- Count the white pixels - i.e. the number of pixels in your shape.
- Load your original image and multiply it with the mask created above.
- Calcuate the mean of the entire image.
- Scale that mean by the number of pixels in the entire image over the number of pixels in the mask.

Some of the writes to `MPR:something` are unnecessary in the following but they show you what I am doing so I left them in:

```
#!/bin/bash
convert image.png -write MPR:orig                                             \
  -print "Pixels in entire image: %[fx:w*h]\n"                                \
  -colorspace gray -threshold 100% -write MPR:black                           \
  -fill white -draw "polygon 50,105 470,105 475,398 50,405" -write MPR:mask   \
  MPR:black                                                                   \
  -metric AE -compare -print "Pixels in polygon: %[distortion]\n" -delete 0   \
  MPR:orig MPR:mask -evaluate-sequence multiply -print "Mean (entire image): %[mean]\n" null:
```

**Output**

```
Pixels in entire image: 597600
Pixels in polygon: 126357
Mean (entire image): 10160.5
```

**Original Answer**

I am leaving the following as a stepping stone because it shows a couple of other techniques and intermediate files...

Another option may be to draw a white filled polygon corresponding to your detected polygon shape, and then set all the other pixels to black. Save that as a mask for later, then count the number of white pixels in the polygon - by copying it and making the copy black then doing a difference between the two - luckily easier than it sounds:

```
convert image.png                                            \
  -fill white -draw "polygon 50,105 470,105 475,398 50,405"  \
  -fill black +opaque white -colorspace gray -write mask.mpc \
  \( +clone -threshold 100% \)                               \
  -metric AE -compare -format "%[distortion]" info:
125642
```

[image]

That tells us that the white area contains 125,642 of the total 597,600 pixels, or roughly 25%.

If we now load the original image and mask it with that mask and determine its average, we can determine the average of the area masked by the white pixels because we know how many are white from the previous step:

```
convert image.png mask.mpc -compose copyopacity -composite -format "%[mean]" info:
22012.6
```

[image]

```
convert image.png mask.mpc -compose copyopacity -composite result.png
```